# Add camera handling on Windows CE C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, camera, windows-ce

I'm trying to develop an application on Windows CE. My device has a camera and I would like to handle it in my application. I've found many samples for windows mobile and try to implement it but without success.
Is there a specific class or assembly for Windows CE about camera handling ???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no generic "camera class" for using camera data under CE.  Windows Mobile has the [CameraCaptureDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.forms.cameracapturedialog.aspx), but it requires a specific software interface that is only required from WinMo OEMs.  Since cameras can have a wide variety of software interfaces and since there is not requirement for any OEM to use any specific one, there wasn't a way for the CF team to wrap it in a control.

In many cases the camera input stream can be gotten through Direct Show.  If your device has DShow and the camera driver provides a DSHow interface (two big ifs) then you can probably create a filtergraph to import it.  Doing so involves a fair bit of complex [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446497.aspx), so it's not what I'd call simple, but it's at least achievable.